# Converting input images to svg in an activity

Tags: android, svg

I was working on an application and I need to change the format of the image file inputed by the user into svg format so I can use it across different screens without making the images weird. I tried to search but all I got was how to convert svg to imageviews. Are there any libraries available that can convert images to svg in an application?

Comment: check android-svg if it has something like this

Answer (score 0):

There's https://svgdotjs.github.io/ if you are using JavaScript.

Comment: He doesn't seem to be using JavaScript at all.

Comment: I was working on an android application and asking if there were any java libraries that could do so!